When can we call somebody a criminal?
In the current Pelicot rape process in Avignon, France, the defendant was sentenced to 20 years in prison by a local criminal court. Can* we (and newspapers) now call him a rapist, even though he still has the possibility to file an appeal? After all, there's a possibility that he will be acquitted in an appelate trial (maybe there was a procedural error). What if he files an appeal and then dies before the appelate court can provide a verdict?
* "Can" in the sense of "is it legal, without risking a defamatory lawsuit" or repercussions from media controlling agencies.

In what jurisdiction are you? Rules for libel/defamation vary wildly.

@Nemo: Switzerland, but I'm interested in answers from any jurisdiction.

Arguably, you just did call him a rapist, so clearly, you can.

In England and Wales, it is impossible to libel the dead.  So you can call Slobodan Milosevic whatever you want, true or false.  In addition, a criminal conviction provides a defence to libel on that point (at least until the conviction is overturned).  Someone more knowledgeable than me might be able to provide references.

@Henry Good point, but that isn't the case everywhere. In Germany for instance, you can go to jail for dishonoring a dead, see https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verunglimpfung_des_Andenkens_Verstorbener

Consider the defamation case between Trump and ABC News. He was found liable of sexual assault, the judge in that case had commented that what he did would commonly be called rape, but Trump sued ABC for defamation when they called him a rapist. They might have won the case, but decided to settle rather than drag it out in court.

If a convicted rapist is acquitted on appeal, can't the newspapers who describe him as such issue a simple apology? Their description is based on fact (Pelicot was convicted and sentenced), not heresay, and a conviction can be overturned many years in the future.

There is no "exceptio veritatis" defense for libel in many countries. Truth doesn't really matter. https://www.hrw.org/legacy/reports98/chile/Chilerpt-04.htm

@Barmar one problem with the word "rape" is that it means different things in different jurisdictions.  Some US states do not have a crime called "rape"; others use the word inconsistently, such that "rape" in one state isn't "rape" in another, and vice versa.

@phoog Indeed, that's precisely why he wasn't found liable for rape in the case in question: New York has a narrow legal definition of it. But the judge said that what he did would be rape "as many people commonly understand the word".

@phoog In the defamation case, Trump claims that Stephanopoulis harmed his reputation by saying he was found liable for rape. It's hard to see how that's the case, considering that he was essentially parrotting what the judge already said. Would his reputation really have been tarnished much less if he'd said "sexual assault" instead. Lawsuit-happy Trump would probably have sued over that as well.

canada
To avoid the risk of a defamation lawsuit, any expression should be clear about whether a person has been accused of, or charged with, or convicted of a particular action or criminal offence. It is also best to communicate whether a person convicted is exercising their right to appeal.
As a cautionary tale, see Hall v. Kyburz, 2006 ABQB 294. A person posted flyers that alleged, among other things, "Calgary Police Officers engage in ‘Break and Enter’ as well as kidnapping" and named several officers. The judge held that the author:

is not at liberty to assert that he can prove that the Applicants are, for example, “criminals” based on his interpretation of the law or on alleged events respecting which no charges or convictions were ever commenced or indeed contemplated.

"[L]oose language and imputations and accusations of criminality" opens one up to the risk of a defamation claim.
Media organizations should describe the facts as scrupulously as are known to them:

what accusations are made and by whom, and what degree of independent verification or justification the organization has for reporting these accusations;*
what charges, if any, have been brought by prosecutors;
what convictions have been made;
what appeal, if any, is available or has been commenced;
etc.


* The Supreme Court of Canada has affirmed that one is not off the hook simply by repeating the allegations of someone else: "one should not be able to freely publish a scurrilous libel simply by purporting to attribute the allegation to someone else." If one reports a defamatory accusation, one is still liable for that defamation unless within the "reportage" exception. "If a dispute is itself a matter of public interest and the allegations are fairly reported, the publisher should incur no liability even if some of the statements made may be defamatory and untrue, provided:  (1) the report attributes the statement to a person, preferably identified, thereby avoiding total unaccountability; (2) the report indicates, expressly or implicitly, that its truth has not been verified; (3) the report sets out both sides of the dispute fairly; and (4) the report provides the context in which the statements were made." Simply saying "alleged" is not a magic word that frees one from liability.

Can you clarify something?  To me it seems that the "not at liberty to assert" passage makes no mention of the truth of the assertion.  In other words, if I personally observed Officer X breaking into someone's apartment and kidnapping him, even if I have video evidence of this, and if the prosecutor declines to pursue the matter, this ruling says that I cannot publish this information.  That is not consistent with what I know of defamation law in other jurisdictions.  Is there some context missing, or is it in fact different from other jurisdictions?

@phoog Based on the defence of "truth", you can say the truth of what you observed, but you should not convey an actual criminal charge or conviction if there has been no charge or conviction. Or based on a "fair comment" defence, you can give your opinion that the facts that you've conveyed may make out an offence.
